# Transferring a 16-bit array from a Raspberry Pi to STM32F4 using SPI

Tags: python, stm32, spi, pi, stm32f4

I have two main question in reference to my end goal of being able to send a 16 bit array of size 2000 from STM32F4 in slave mode to a raspberry pi in master mode.

Question 1. I don't understand why I am reading/printing the incorrect output on my Pi when sending from my STM. I have explained my programming and the resulting output.

Initially i'm testing with transmitting an 8 bit integer, as the HAL_SPI_Transmit function prototype is only allowing 8 bit transmission (This is my Question 2), so I have set up for 8 bit transmission for now and my 8 bits is transferring incorrectly. My STM32F4 is configured to 8 bit slave mode using CubeMX which generates the following block of code.

```
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

/* SPI2 parameter configuration*/
hspi2.Instance = SPI2;

hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;

hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE;

hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;

hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;

hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;

hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;

hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;

hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;

hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;

hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;

if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}


}
```

Using the HAL Library, I am currently set up to transmit an 8 bit array (array spiDATA is of type uint8_t) using the HAL_SPI_Transmit function as shown in the following passage of code. In the following passage, I am just trying to send the first entry of the array spiDATA.

```
while (1)

{

  spiDATA[0]=5;

  spiDATA[1]=7;

  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, spiDATA, 1, 10);

 }
```

Now over on the Pi, the code to receive the data on the STM looks like

```
#initialise spiDEV

spi = spidev.SpiDev()

spi.open(0,0)

spi.max_speed_hz = 100000

TRUE = 1

while TRUE:

y = spi.readbytes(1)

print("Value tranferred by SPI is", y[0])

time.sleep(1)
```

Now when running this, the output on the pi is as shown

```
("Value tranferred by SPI is", 80)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 65)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 5)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 10) 

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 20)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 40)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 80)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 65)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 5)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 10)
```

If I change the HAL_SPI_Transmit to send 2 bytes, and change the readbytes to 2 bytes, and print both y[0] and y[1], it prints the same thing twice, for example it would look like

```
("Value tranferred by SPI is", 80, 80)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 65, 65)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 5, 5)

etc
```

Now if I change HAL_SPI_Transmit to transmit 4 bytes and readbytes to 2 bytes, I get the following,

```
("Value tranferred by SPI is", 5, 7)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 0, 20)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 56, 40)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 112, 80)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 224, 160)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 193, 65)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 130, 112)

("Value tranferred by SPI is", 5, 7)
```

Question 2: Is it possible to send 16 bits using the HAL_SPI_Transmit function? In the HAL_SPI_Transmit function prototype, it says it requires an 8 bit pointer to the data as shown below.

```
HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

I have reconfigured my pin for 16 bit transmission using cubeMX which regenerates the initialisation code shown earlier and assigns,

```
hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;
```

But I still have the problem that when I try and send 16 bits, when communicating to the Pi over SPI, it truncates my 16 bit integer into an 8 bit integer. I have seen that this has been posted in forums elsewhere, where the suggested answer is to type-cast the *pdata in the prototype, for example my function would be change to (uint8_t*)spiData' in the HAL_SPI_Transmit. This doesn't work as I require 11 to 12 bits to express integers in my range, which have values like '2000' and '3000' etc. by type casting, I am losing this information as it is truncating the bits.

Comment: The STM32 has the slave role. It will send data if chip select is asserted and the master provides a clock. Your STM32 probably never sends any data because the SPI chip select is never triggered. Either use hardware NSS and wire it correctly, or enable it by software (SSI bit in SPI_CR1 register). The latter one only works if this is the only slave on the SPI bus and if the master stops the clock while not transmitting.

Comment: And forget about 16 bit mode. It's not needed and will just make everything more complex. A 16 bit number can easily be transferred as two 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The SPI transmission error can be due to many issues.

- You need to make sure that your **kernel clock is high enough** to handle the data reception. If your SPI clock frequency bus is lower that the Raspberry Pi Spi baud rate.
- From the SPI ST presentation: User can prevent any glitches on the associated outputs working on alternate function mode by ***keeping them forced under control***. This means you need to configure and force your GPIO SCK, MOSI, NSS on ***pull down*** resistor (or pull up).
- Use Hardware NSS in your stm32 configuration.
- Enable CS (Disable No CS) in your Raspberry pi.
- Try to send long sized buffer (e.g: 256)